# Best way to replace computed properties of vue in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

In my vue application, i am changing my vue components to react. While doing this, i came over that computed properties of vue. After checking ,there is no such properties in React. So, i memoized the function and creating like computed result.

Is this the correct way to do this?

**Vue**

```
addedClass() {
 let clazz = [];
  if( this.top )         {clazz.push('my-area--top')}
                else if( this.middle ) {clazz.push('my-area--middle')}
                else if( this.bottom ) {clazz.push('my-area--bottom')}
                if( this.left )       {clazz.push('my-area--left')}
                else if( this.right ) {clazz.push('my-area--right')}
                if( this.fullPage ) {clazz.push('my-area--full-page')}
                if( this.dev) clazz.push('my-area--dev');
                if( this.bordered ) {
                    clazz.push('my-area--bordered');
                }

                return clazz.join(' ');
}
```

In React component, i am doing this using **useMemo**

```
    const addedClass = useMemo(() => {
        let clazz = [];
            if( props.top )   
                {clazz.push('my-area--top')}
                else if( props.middle ) {clazz.push('my-area--middle')}
                else if( props.bottom ) {clazz.push('my-area--bottom')}
                if( props.left )       {clazz.push('my-area--left')}
                else if( props.right ) {clazz.push('my-area--right')}
                if( props.fullPage ) {clazz.push('my-area--full-page')}
                if( props.dev) clazz.push('my-area--dev');
                if(props.bordered ) {
                    clazz.push('my-area--bordered');
                }

                return clazz.join(' ');
    })
```

I am not sure as i am in correct path or not. Till i haven't tested yet just want to know if i missed something in this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea of memoizing the class names is fine, but there's a big problem - you're re-computing the value every time the component renders because there's no dependency array. Given your current code, you may as well not be using `useMemo` at all.

This is a very inexpensive process, so:

- Either don't worry about memoization, and just construct the class name string each render (which would be perfectly reasonable)
- Or properly memoize the class name by putting all dependent values into the dependency array

  ```
  useMemo(() => {
  }, [this.top, this.middle, this.bottom]); // etc
  ```

  (do the values you want to check really exist on `this`? That sounds extraordinarily strange in a functional component where you're using hooks like `useMemo`. You probably want to reference props or a state value instead.)

Comment: Sorry i edited that. Those are props

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. 2nd approach i am able to understand but 1st one can you give some example on that?

Comment: Just leave off the `useMemo` entirely and construct the array and then the string in the main body of the component. Remove `const addedClass = useMemo(() => {` and the final `})`, and replace `return clazz.join(' ');` with `const addedClass = clazz.join(' ');` Maybe also use a more meaningful name than `clazz`. (precise variable names really help when trying to read over a section of code)